# PHP: Uploading file to google drive with service account

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a pdf to google drive as a service account in php.

I get a browser error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when trying to upload.

I got the code from here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts#next_steps
and
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

```
<?php

require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
session_start();

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'API Project-xxx.p12';

/**
 * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts.
 *
 * @return Google_DriveService service object.
 */
function buildService() {
global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}


/**
 * Insert new file.
 *
 * @param Google_DriveService $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
 * @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
 * @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
 * @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
 * @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
 * @return Google_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new Google_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}



$service=buildService();
$title='test';
$description='qqq';
$parentId='';
$mimeType='application/pdf';
$filename='doc.pdf';

insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename)   
?>
```